# Google Visualization API: how to apply a pattern on addColumn

Tags: javascript, formatting, google-visualization

When I try to specify a pattern in `addColumn`, it does not show. What do I do wrong?

```
data.addColumn({
  type: 'date',
  label: 'Date',
  pattern: "EE dd MMM yyyy"
});
data.addRow([new Date(2016, 02, 05)])
```

Displayed value is `Mar 5, 2016` which is the default format, while I expected `Sat 05 Mar 2016` as specified in `addColumn({pattern: "EE dd MMM yyyy"})`

See https://jsfiddle.net/qpq3kvhr/3 where the same issue also exists for a `number`.

I googled for a working example of `addColumn(pattern)`, but did not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [addColumn documententation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addColumn) states:

> `addColumn(type, opt_label, opt_id)`
>   OR
>   `addColumn(description_object)`
>   Second signature has a single object parameter with the following members:
>   ...
>
> - `pattern` - [*Optional*, string] A number (or date) format string **specifying how to display** the column value.

But this is wrong or at least confusing. It is explained differently in the documentation for the [Constructor's JavaScript Literal data parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

> `cols` **Property**
>
> `cols` is an array of objects describing the ID and type of each column.
>   Each property is an object with the following properties
>   (case-sensitive):
>   ...
>
> - `pattern` [*Optional*] String pattern **that was used** by a data source 
>     to format numeric, date, or time column values.  This is for reference
>     only; you probably won't need to read the pattern,  and it isn't
>     required to exist. **The Google Visualization client does not use this
>     value** (it reads the cell's formatted value).  If the DataTable has
>     come from a data source in response  to a query with a format clause,
>     the pattern you specified in that clause will probably be returned in
>     this value.

Conclusion: you cannot specify an automatically applied format pattern in a dataTable or addColumn constructor. Instead, apply a [formatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters) to a column afterwards.

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: "EE dd MMM yyyy"});
formatter.format(data, 0);
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qpq3kvhr/6/